# Drupal 6 and multiple versions of PHP

Tags: php, drupal

My still requires me to run Drupal 6  (yes I understand the risks).  I have multiple versions of PHP installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 - 5.6, 7, 7.2.3.  The 7.2.3. is being used by Laravel and my Drupal 7 installs.  I tried making updates to Drupal 6 but it keeps on complaining about the mbsting.http_input.  Even though I have updated the  php.ini for 7.23 it is still there.  Is there a way that I can point drupal 6 to PHP 5.6 while still keeping 7.2.3 for the rest?

To add some additional context - when I log to my drupal 6 blog and go to install.php it says drupal already installed.  But when I go to the main page it show 500 error.

Comment: For Drupal 6 & 7 I'd recommend PHP 5.6 and only for Drupal 8 it should be PHP 7.1

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use different PHP versions per vhost. But it's quite fiddly to setup (at least for me it was). Have a look at [`mod_proxy_fcgi`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html) and  `ProxyPassMatch`.

I once managed to set this up in Docker ([Dockerfile](https://github.com/leymannx/apache-multiphp/blob/master/Dockerfile)). Natively I guess it must go along the lines of the following Apache confs.

#### `drupal6.com.conf`

```
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName drupal6.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/php56

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/php56error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/php56access.log combined

    ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/php56"
    <Directory "/var/www/php56">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride FileInfo All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

#### `drupal7.com.conf`

```
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName drupal7.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/php72

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/php72error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/php72access.log combined

    ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/php72"
    <Directory "/var/www/php72">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride FileInfo All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

---

For Nginx take the following approach as starting point ([source](https://pehapkari.cz/blog/2017/03/27/multiple-php-versions-the-easy-way/)).

1. `$ git clone https://gist.github.com/2fca8bfdc5004bade15bac84b9ab73e7.git test/multiphp`
2. `$ docker build -t nginx-multiphp test/multiphp`
3. `$ docker run -p 8856:8856 -p 8871:8871 --rm -P nginx-multiphp`
4. In your browser visit: `http://localhost:8856` for PHP56 and `http://localhost:8871` for PHP71 accordingly.
5. Happy happy

Comment: Thanks.  It actually gets worse.. Drupal 6 is sitting in a Laravel sub-directory.  But looks like the option is to crate a subdomain and point it there.

Comment: @user9465677 – Challenging :) Good luck pal!

Comment: Would this command unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/php56 work on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Finally got around testing this - ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/php56" causes the apache2 restart failure.  I get "Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code."